# VSCode extension installation fails without errors

Tags: proxy, configuration, visual-studio-code

### Problem

Hi, whenever I try to install an extension in VSCode the installation is canceled without any error message showing up.

[image: Before installation]
Before installation

[image: During Installation]
During Installation

[image: VSCode jumps back into this state]
VSCode jumps back into this state

### Question

How can I figure out **any details** about what the problem is? Is there some hidden error log or anything?

### A Wild Guess

Im currently on a machine where my administration rights or the proxy configuration may be insufficient. This may be the cause of the problem. Installing an extension manually into the VSCode installation folder, worked.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution: Installation via Command Line

Installing extensions using the terminal gives at least some error message:

```
C:\some\path>code --install-extension some-publisher.some-extension
Found 'msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome' in the marketplace.
Installing...
Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1117:19)
    ...
```

### Finding out `some-publisher.some-extension`

The publisher and extension can easily be copied from the extension details:
[image]